# cmake: how to create NAMED custom target WITH output, so it does not build if output is there

Tags: makefile, cmake, target

I'm looking for a way in CMake to add custom targets, but **that does not rebuild, if the dependencies are older than the outputs.** The problem is that `add_custom_target` will always rebuild, because it does not have an output condition, and the problem with `add_custom_command` is that does not create a target.

Is there something that does both (but does not involve `add_executable` and `add_library`, as my targets have zero thing to do with a compiler.)

Thanks.

Comment: The common approach in CMake to call `add_custom_command` which contains proper DEPENDS and COMMAND, and then call `add_custom_target` without COMMAND, and which just depends on `add_custom_command`'s OUTPUT. That way you will have a named target, which rebuilds files only when dependencies are changed (newer).

Comment: Ah. I see. Understand it now. Cmake is painfully unintuitive.

Comment: "Cmake is painfully unintuitive." - This is quite subjective. E.g. unlike to Make, CMake fully separates **file-level** dependencies, when output file is rebuilt if one of its dependencies is updated, and **target-level** dependencies, when a target is build only after a dependent one.

Comment: Yes, but if you think about it, CMake forces a procedural generation scheme on an inherently declarative description of dependencies. And instead of using an existing language, they invented some very obscure language. Which has all the drawbacks of being procedural, but not really the advantages. They whole thing could have been solved by a Python library, giving much more flexibility. Even "readable" CMake files are not that readable. And again: describing dependencies is absolutely a declarative task.